# more_than_30_sec event in GA4 strange behavior

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, event-tracking

In GA4 while reviewing Page Paths, I noticed a large amount of (not set) Pages, with 0 Views but a lot of Users - see screenshot.

I am trying to understand how this is possible, but no additional info is available about the pages (url, title, description - nothing), except for the fact that they are somehow related with the more_than_30_sec event - see last column.

This is an automatic event tracked by GA4. At the same time, the average engagement time is 0s for this group.

So, what could be the issue here?

Page paths / titles etc. are tracked for quite a lot of other pages (there are 292k views).

[image: (not set) page path for event more_thank_30_sec]

Comment: Maybe you can use `Explorere` report to see the related event or other dimension to tell which is causing this issue. Or the `more_than_30_secs` event only fire in `not set` page path?

Comment: Yes, I tried the Explorer - the (not set) Page Paths are visited from different countries, different sources (paid and organic), on different date. And besides this, all other dimensions, when selected, come back with zeros in the metrics columns. And yes, all (not set) Page Paths are related to the more_than_30_sec events and vice versa.

Comment: Basically you have a user  on a page and page view has not been triggered. 
I would check you don't have an app lurking about sending user ids, 
next check session starts in the event count, if you have a high number of starts but no views you have it could be a page load speed challenge with users leaving before the page loads.
 It could be problem with tag manager, if you can replicate this in an Exploration and add URL, this will show if there is no page information or if your tag manager is not working.

Comment: I think I found an explanation for this - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9934109?hl=en

As I said, when the respective requirements for the audience are met, the event is triggered. Metadata is copied to the event, but "Copied metadata includes timestamp and session information but does not include the page/screen associated with the event." The event is only useful for the audience creation, but cannot be used for analysis of which pages were visited etc. Unless you create the event from GTM and not through the GA4 Audience builder.